# В терминал ничего не выводится при выполнении команды node?

Tags: node.js, bash, debian, docker

Запустил контейнер. `bash debian:jessie`
Далее захожу в папку и вызываю `node`:

```
cd /server/
node file.js
```

Но ничего не выводится в терминал. Хотя там ошибки должны быть. Если делать тоже самое на машине хоста, то там выводятся ошибки.
`node -v` тоже ничего не выводит.

Но если ввести `node2` то выводит

> bash: node2: command not found

Можно ли как то перенаправить вывод в текущее окно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: проблема явно не в программе *docker*, не в перенаправлении вывода и не в текущем окне. проблема в том, что вы не знаете, какие действия производит оболочка при указании выполнить команду `node` (команда — это **НЕ** программа). для начала: см. вывод `$ command -V node` внутри контейнера

Comment: root@manking-OMEN-by-HP-Laptop:/# **command -V node**


_node is hashed (/usr/sbin/node)_

Comment: То есть node js даже не запускается?